# Approximate a decimal by excess

Tags: python

I want to create a vector whose components are `q` rational numbers going from `0.` to a given number `n`. I can do this with the following algorithm

```
import numpy as np
n = 60.
q=200
dn = 1.*n/q

X=np.arange(0.,n,dn)
print len(X)
```

It should return `200`.
this method works in certain cases, like in the example above. However, it might happen that `dn` is a rational or periodic number. In that case it is not approximated by excess and thus the length of `X` ends up being `q+1` instead of `q`.
For example, in the case `q=220` the algorithm returns `221` instead of `220`.
What is the best way to avoid this issue?

Comment: I solved the problem by writing `dn=1.*n/q+10**(-3)`, but I would like a more elegant solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you want [`linspace`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.15.0/reference/generated/numpy.linspace.html)

```
X = np.linspace(0, n, q)
```

This is similar to:

```
gen = (i * n / (q-1.0) for i in range(q))
X = np.fromiter(gen, float)
```